# How do I bind DBI parameters at runtime in Perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

I have the following  code :

```
sub run_query { 
    my $name = shift || undef;
    my $sql  = (defined $name ) ? "select * from table where name = ?" :
                                  "select * from table";
    my $sth  = $dbh->prepare("$sql");
    $sth->execute($name);
}
```

The above subroutine need to work as follows: if `$name` is provided, then run the first query, else fetch all the data from the table.  How can I bind the `name` field?  I'd like it bound dynamically if it is provided.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: if not provided name and $sth->execute($name) run .

Comment: my $name = shift;  # || undef is not needed... You should not quote lone variables, $dbh->prepare($sql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [DBI documentation on cpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI):

> A common issue is to have a code fragment handle a value that could be
>   either defined or undef (non-NULL or NULL) at runtime. A simple
>   technique is to prepare the appropriate statement as needed, and
>   substitute the placeholder for non-NULL cases:

```
  $sql_clause = defined $age ? "age = ?" : "age IS NULL";
  $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
    SELECT fullname FROM people WHERE $sql_clause
  });
  $sth->execute(defined $age ? $age : ());
```

It does not exactly apply to your question, which I *assume* is that your execute fails if you add an argument where one is not expected. So, the last line here would apply:

```
  $sth->execute(defined $name ? $name : ());
```

Comment: Ternary operators also work in list context so you can say `my ($sql, @args) = defined $name ? ('select ...', $name) : ('select ...');` and `$sth->execute(@args);` to keep the conditional logic all in one place.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably have two different subs, but you could use

```
sub run_query { 
    my $sql = @_
       ? "select * from table where name = ?"
       : "select * from table";
    my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(@_);
}
```

Comment: @smith, Note that "not provided" is not the same thing as "not defined". I answered the actual question (Not provided: `@_ ? $name : ()`) and the TLP and bvr answered the latter (Not defined: `defined($name) ? $name : ()`). That said, the distinction is surely irrelevant in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally omit parameters if `$name` is not defined:

```
$sth->execute(defined $name ? $name : ());
```